# How to use different .vimrc than what is the default .vimrc

Tags: vim

I share lab server with my colleagues, but want my separate .vimrc file. How to get that?

```
$ cat .vimrc
color desert

$ pwd
/fvs101/home
```

We have our separate working directory, so my directory is inside 
/fvs101/home/sp

At /fvs101/home there is common .vimrc file. 
I want to play with vim but do not want to touch this /fvs101/home/.vimrc file.
I want to create my own .vimrc file.

```
++++++++++my vimrc file
[sp]$ cat .vimrc
noremap - ddp
noremap _ dd2kp
inoremap <c-u> <esc>lviwU<esc>i
nnoremap <c-u> <esc>viwU<esc>
let mapleader = "-"
let maplocalleader = "\\"
nnoremap <leader>ev :vsplit $MYVIMRC<cr>
nnoremap <leader>sv :source $MYVIMRC<cr>
iabbrev ssig -- <cr>Sachin Pawar<cr>sachin.sp.pawar@oracle.com
vnoremap <leader>' vi<esc>`<<esc>i'<esc>`><esc>i'<esc>
nnoremap H 0
nnoremap L $
inoremap jk <esc>
inoremap <esc> <nop>
augroup filetype_js
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType javascript nnoremap <buffer> <localleader>c I//<esc>
augroup END
augroup filetype_python
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType python     nnoremap <buffer> <localleader>c I#<esc>
augroup END
augroup filetype_sql
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType sql     nnoremap <buffer> <localleader>c I--esc>
augroup END
augroup filetype_shell
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType shell     nnoremap <buffer> <localleader>c I#esc>
augroup END
augroup filetype_html
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType html nnoremap <buffer> <localleader>f Vatzf
augroup END
++++++++++
```

If i use my separate .vimrc file i am not able to see the mapping for some mappings like

> inoremap jk

Why is this happening and how to avoid it.

In order to use my own .vimrc file i have create a separate alias.

> alias vi='vim -u /fvs101/home/sp/.vimrc'

Answer (score 5):

Make a different .vimrc (as you have stated in the comments, `/refresh/oracle/spawar/.vimrc`) and make an alias for your own user

```
myvi='vim -Nu /refresh/oracle/spawar/.vimrc'
```

Note that without the `-N` flag, using the `-u` flag will start vim in compatibility mode causing all sorts of nasty, unexpected side-effects such as mappings not working entirely.

I found this out by going to see what the `-u` flag really does and following from there. 
Helpful links below.

[u flag](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#-u)
[N flag](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#-N)

Answer (score 2):

Seeing as you specifically want everyone to log into the same user, the easiest way I can think of how to do this is if you make your own .vimrc (give it a short name, such as `~/.vrc`) and every time you open vim, you type

```
:so ~/.vrc
```

which will load that vimrc for you. Every time you open vim it will use the defaults, until you load your own vimrc, so you will have to do this each and every time. Also remember that this way, `~/.vimrc` loads automatically before you manually load `~/.vrc`

Comment: You are right, but it doesnt work properly for below kind of mapping:inoremap jk <esc>

Comment: I'm not sure I understand where the problem lies then.

What actions did you take?
What did you expect to happen?
What did you observe to happen?
What did you suspect caused it to happen?

Comment: I think i didnt explain well enough. my this mapping is not working "inoremap jk <esc>" I DO NOT want to edit the .vimrc at the home location ( which everyone shares) . So what i am doing for my own user is alias vi='vim -u /refresh/oracle/spawar/.vimrc' . But unfortunately when i am trying edit any file. and pressing jk in insert mode, it is not replacing to escape, instead i am seeing <esc> . Apologies for the late reply , i got crazy stuck in prod issues.

Comment: @Sach I found the solution to your problem and posted it as a separate answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can call *Vim* with a different runtime configuration file than the default one with

```
vim -N -u path/to/your/vimrc
```

If you want to use this always, edit your users shell runtime configuration to define an alias for that.

```
alias vim="vim -N -u path/to/your/vimrc"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest solution would be to append a single line to the end of the default vimrc which reads:

```
source ~/.vimrc.local  " Or whatever you want to call it
```

Where `.vimrc.local` contains your custom configuration.

Comment: No. that would not work because i do not want my colleagues which login to the same server as same user i.e. Oracle to get stumped by my custom vim settings .  So i do NOT want to edit the default vimrc file :(